# Errors when loading csv to BiQuery using Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to load a csv in BigQuery using Python API. I am getting the following errors: 
RuntimeError: [{u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Too many errors encountered.'}, {u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Too many values in row starting at position: 0.', u'location': u'mediaupload-snapshot'}]

From what I have searched on the internet, I need to specify maxBadRecords and allowJaggedRows etc. but I do not understand where to specify this.

The code I am writing to load data from csv to bigquery is :

```
def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)
def load_data_from_file(dataset_name, table_name, source_file_name):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table = dataset.table(table_name)


    table.reload()

    with open(source_file_name, 'rb') as source_file:
        job = table.upload_from_file(
            source_file, source_format='text/csv')

    wait_for_job(job)

    print('Loaded {} rows into {}:{}.'.format(
    job.output_rows, dataset_name, table_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are mistaking the argument to `upload_from_file` ?

`source_format` is different from yours.

```
with open('csv_file', 'rb') as readable:
    table.upload_from_file(
        readable, source_format='CSV', skip_leading_rows=1)
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/bc11ccbb63b5937f73c6ec092f911885d2376dae/bigquery/README.rst#load-data-from-csv

Comment: Even after making this change, its not working for me.

Comment: I am getting this error : RuntimeError: [{u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Too many errors encountered.'}, {u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Too many values in row starting at position: 0.', u'location': u'mediaupload-snapshot'}]

Comment: Perhaps I think that "mediaupload-snapshot" is a CSV file. Does the CSV match the table scheme of BigQuery?  Without CSV file and Table scheme, I do not know any more.

Answer (score 0):

With the big query jobId you use this UI to get the details

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get

Enter the projectId and the jobId